# Revit cannot run external aplication (PyRevit)

Tags: revit, pyrevit

I installed pyRevit as documentation say, but doesnt work. I installed more times and I had never had thar error. Then I updated, but dont work too. I share the error pic.

[image]

Someone could help me ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to check is the dependencies of `PyRevitLoader.dll`. Use the `DependenciesGui.exe` tool (https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) and open the DLL. This should list all the dependencies of the `PyRevitLoader.dll`. Drill down into all the dependencies to see if there are any that can't be found.

Comment: @FranciscoPossetto for the next guy: How did you solve it? What did the problem turn out to be?

Comment: I fixed the error immediately using the Installer pyRevitSetup.exe. 
But out of curiosity, I uninstalled pyRevit and followed the steps that you indicated me. 
1. Download Dependencies and run DependenciesGui.
2. Load the file PyRevitLoader.dll.

The following dependencies are lost:

xpaxholder.dll
ext-ms-windowscore-deviceinfo-l1-1-0.dll
ext-ms-win-core-winrt-remote-l1-1-0.dll

I suppose the Installer has solved these problems repairing the missing  dll. Does it Makes sense? Or did something else happen?